# Implementing history of PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-partitioning

I want to implement history of changes of PostgreSQL table. The table is defined the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE "ps_counters"
(
    "psid" integer NOT NULL,
    "counter" bigint[] NOT NULL
);
```

I want the history table to look like:

```
CREATE TABLE "ps_counters_history"
(
    "timestamp" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "psid" integer NOT NULL,
    "counter" bigint[] NOT NULL
);
```

I need a trigger and a stored procedure which on every change (insertion or update) in `ps_couneters` to insert in `ps_counters_history`, but in addition to prevent `ps_counters_history` to became too big I want partitioning of `ps_counters_history` table on every month.

Comment: Too big? How many ps_counters changes are there per month?

Comment: OK, so you've described the solution in quite a lot of detail. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) and [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to implement it.

```
CREATE TABLE "ps_counters_history"
(
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "timestamp" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
  "psid" integer NOT NULL,
  "counter" bigint[] NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ps_counters_history_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    table_name text;
  BEGIN
    table_name := 'ps_counters_history_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy_mm');
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class WHERE relname = table_name)
    THEN
      EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || table_name ||
              ' () INHERITS (ps_counters_history);';
    END IF;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name ||
            '(psid, counter) VALUES ($1.psid, $1.counter);' USING NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
  END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ps_counters_history_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ps_counters FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ps_counters_history_trigger();
```

Comment: Just several suggestions: 1) Usually table should have a primary key 2) `now()` returns the time when the transaction starts, `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual time 3) `execute` can be used with parameters: `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || '(psid, counter) VALUES ($1.psid, $1.counter);' USING NEW;`

Comment: FYI, your create if not exists logic will break if two concurrent transactions try to run it at once. You'll get a table-already-exists error despite the "if not exists" check.

Comment: @Craig Ringer If I use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` instead of `CREATE TABLE` inside the if, would it prevent the error? How you suggest to fix this?

Comment: @bobeff Hello, did you find a solution? In your question above, I think it's better if you create the history tables upfront, e.g. in your database connection initialization, so inside the trigger you only INSERT rows and not create tables (solves the concurrency issues when using CREATE TABLE/ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS).

Comment: Why not create partitioning tables in advance? What is the point in dealing we table creation at insert time if you might have one ready a year ahead?