# How can I automatically maintain a dump of modified rows in PostGreSql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

So, I have a PostGreSQL DB. For some chosen tables in that DB I want to maintain a plain dump of the rows when modified. Note this dump is not a recovery or backup dump. It is just a file which will have the incremental rows. That is, whenever a row is inserted or updated, I want that appended to this file or to a file in a folder. Idea is to load that folder into say something like hive periodically so that I can run queries to check previous states of certain rows, columns. Now, these are very high transactional tables and the dump does not need to be real time. It can be in batches, every hour. I want to avoid a trigger firing hundreds of times every minute. I am looking for something which is off the shelf - already available in PostGreSQL. I did some research but everything is related to PostGreSQL backup - which is not the exact use case.

I have read some links like https://clarkdave.net/2015/02/historical-records-with-postgresql-and-temporal-tables-and-sql-2011/ [Implementing history of PostgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954139/implementing-history-of-postgresql-table) etc - but these are based on insert update trigger and create the history table on PostGreSQL itself. I want to avoid both. I cannot have the history on PostGreSQL as it will be huge soon. And I do not want to keep writing to files through a trigger firing constantly.

Comment: Why not log your transactions to file in addition to writing to a database table?

Comment: That is my backup plan. I am trying to make is tight. Basically writing to file will not be part of my database transaction so there can be potential mistakes and then I will have to manage transnational failures etc. Additionally my rows will have many columns whereas I might be updating only few. If I am writing to a file myself, I will have to first fetch all the columns of all the rows I will update etc to keep the complete last state.

Comment: K, I don’t understand your requirements

Comment: Say I have a million rows in a table. Few hundred thousands are being updated every minute. Each row has say 20 columns. Each update may be on 5 to 10 columns of these 20. I want a file which will have the last state of each row - all 20 columns - whenever there is an insert of update on a row. Like a history table. Does that explain ?. This is not for recovery etc. These files will be loaded into a hive table to let me fire historical queries. It will soon grow into TBs so cannot keep history on PostGreSQL itself. And it is not needed to be hot either.

Comment: Right, I think logging to file while you hit the database would work. You may want to look into a message queue too... I think I’m just not understanding some of the limitations on your end.

Comment: Like I said, logging to a file and message queue is what is already I have in my head but I am thinking there must be something simple which I can do in PostGreSQL itself which will maintain the ACID part of this. Like can PostGreSQL or a tool extract history from WAL archives ? So I run this tool every hour and it spits out all the updates on a table. Row by row into a text file.